# Rails 4 - Select tag from collection using Acts as Taggable gem with select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on, html-select

In my rails app I have two models: `Team` and `Post`, each `Post` can have multiple tags, and each `Team` can have many `Posts`. In my team's show action I want to present a `select_tag` with which the user can select one tag of all the created tags for it's posts. When the user selects a tag using the `select_tag` I only want to show the posts that also have that tag. I use the `Acts as Taggable On` gem.

What I currently have is this (I'm using `HAML`):

```
= select_tag "tags", options_from_collection_for_select(@posts, "tags", :tag_list)
```

This give me a select that looks something like this:

```
[row 1] Tag 1
[row 2] Tag 1, Tag 2
[...]
```

What I want is a select list  that looks like this:

```
[row 1] Tag 1
[row 2] Tag 2
[row 3] Tag 3
[...]
```

I haven't used `select_tag` much. Would it be possible to do what I want somehow? And how would that look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two aspects to this: showing the correct tag list, and filtering the posts by the selected tag.

### Showing the correct tag list

You want to create a `<select>` element that only contains tags for that team's posts. [`options_from_collection_for_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select) takes 3 parameters: a collection, a method to get the value for each option, and a method to get the name of each option. So you should be passing a set of **tags** to `options_from_collection_for_select`, not a set of **posts**. And that set of tags shouldn't be all tags - just the ones for your team's posts. Fortunately, [`acts_as_taggable_on`](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) provides a method to do that so you can build tag clouds.

So you're going to update your controller to look something like this:

```
class TeamController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @team = Team.find params[:id]
        @posts = team.posts
        @team_tags = team.posts.tag_counts_on(:tags)
    end
end
```

And update your view to use `@team_tags` instead:

```
= select_tag "tag", options_from_collection_for_select(@team_tags, 'id', 'name')
```

This should give you a select box populated with the tags specific to that team.

### Filtering posts by tag

Now we've got the correct tag list, we want to be able to filter posts by tag. That `<select>` tag should be within a form; you can either create a new controller action that handles that form, or adapt your `show` method accordingly. The latter's a bit trickier, so I've taken that approach here. Let's update your view to make the assumptions clearer:

```
= form_tag team_path(@team), method: 'get', class: 'tag_form' do
  = select_tag "tag", options_from_collection_for_select(@team_tags, 'id', 'name', @tag)
  = submit_tag "Filter posts"
```

And update the controller action to filter the posts, if we've got a 'tags' parameter:

```
class TeamController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @team = Team.find params[:id]
        @team_tags = team.posts.tag_counts_on(:tags)
        if params[:tag]
            @tag = Tag.find params[:tag]
            @posts = team.posts.tagged_with @tag.name
        else
            @tag = nil
            @posts = team.posts
        end
    end
end
```

Notice that we're passing in the selected tag as the instance variable `@tag`, and using that in our `options_from_collection_for_select` to select the right tag if we chose a filter.

### The icing on the cake

You can use a little jQuery and CoffeeScript to hide your submit button and make the filtering happen automatically when the user chooses a new tag, which will improve your user experience a bit. Add this to `app/assets/javascripts/teams.js.coffee`:

```
$ ->
    $forms = $('.tag_form')
    $forms.each (i, el) -> 
        $('input[type=submit]', el).hide()
        $('select', el).on 'change', (ev) -> 
            $(el).submit()
```

This works by finding all elements with a class of `tag_form`, removes all `<input type="submit">` elements within each one, and then listens for [change events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) on the select elements within those forms.

Comment: Thanks, great answer! I got it to work, had to do two minor modifications. I had to add `do` to the `form_tag` line. And to get the right posts I had to do: `@posts = @team.posts.tagged_with(@tag.name)`.

Comment: Thanks for the fixes! I've updated my post with these so future people don't have to fix this separately. :)

Comment: One additional question, do you know if it would be possible to use the `select_tag` with nested resources. So I would get URLs that look something like this: `teams/1/tags/tag-name`. With a resource that looks like this: `resources :teams do get 'tags/:tag', to: "teams#show", as: :tag end`. How would the `select_tag` line look in that case?